# How can do repeatable job every m minutes between start hour until end hours for n days?

Tags: python

I import schedule package in python and i need to run my task for example for n days starts at 1:00 and ends at 1:30 every 10 minutes (3 times per day) and need repeat this pattern until n days finish.
many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to schedule jobs: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

How to clear a scheduled job: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#clear-job-by-tag

```
import schedule

n_days = 5 # Run for 5 days
tasks_done = 0 # Track number of times this is run
tasks_per_day = 3 # No of times this task runs

def do_task():
    global tasks_done, tasks_per_day, n_days
    tasks_done += 1
    print("I'm working...")
    if tasks_done >= (tasks_per_day * n_days):
        # N Days are over
        schedule.clear('daily-tasks')


times = ["01:00", "01:10", "01:20"]

for t in times:
    schedule.every().day.at(t).do(do_task).tag('daily-tasks', t)
```